# Recommended practice to store a mail template

Tags: c#, email

My application sends notification mails to users so I created a html template for each type of notification. I set something like fields in the template as {n} in order to use something like this when I'm sending the message:

```
string bodyTemplate = GetBodyTemplate(); //gets the html template with {n} in it
message.Body = String.Format(bodyTemplate, fieldZeroValue, fieldOneValue);
```

For example, the template can have a piece of this:

```
<td style="vertical-align:middle;padding:0.5em 0.5em 0.5em 0.5em;">
    <a href="www.mypage1az.com\SomePage.aspx?Id={0}">Go to page</a>
</td>
```

In this example I would use:

```
message.Body = String.Format(bodyTemplate, IdValue.ToString());
```

**Here is my question:** Where should I store those very long string with the html templates?
I don't want to connect to the the database to get them and storing them in string constants   looks awful.

Please tell me what is the recomended practice to store those strings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I create text files and store the templates in the project.  If there aren't too many, you could build them into your assembly and get them out of the Resources.  If there are a lot, I would point to a directory that contains the files and use a string reader to pick out a filename.

Comment: I think this make sense. I'm already implementing it, Thanks and +1. I will wait a while to see if there are some others ideas on how to manage this though.

Answer (score 1):

I heard a pearl of wisdom the other day over an argument of using #regions or not.  The "pro #regions" guy said, "But I want to hide ugly code" and the "anti #regions" guy said "if it's so ugly, you shouldn't have written it."

It made me laugh to see that you were getting a code smell from ugly constants.

What is the aversion to putting it in the db? is it the cost of having to get it frequently? If that's so, then perhaps cache it and re-pull from the db at a reasonable interval.  That way you can maintain the flexibility of being able to add or change templates without having to hit the db every time.

If constants would genuenly work and you're bawlking that they're ugly, then hide them with a #region :)

Comment: Yeah, regions are not meant for that, I'm agree. Regarding the DB, I wont put the templates there even if there where no connection cost; that would be like storing text for each label there. Think on the maintaining process for the templates: that task has nothing to do with the database.

Comment: yeah, i was joking about the regions... thought the smily face was enough.  And I disagree that they shouldn't belong in the db... If I have a worker role or something that is getting a list (from the db) of queued email request that need to be sent, why would I go back to a flat file when everything else concerning the email that I need to send is in the db... I've now had to make that DB call and do a file read. I will ceed this point if you're using a schema-less db or using a message queuing system, but otherwise I still go w/ DB

Comment: Guess my english is still baed, I'm agree with you about the regions issue. About the DB, Maybe if you have a lot of templates it is the way to go, but since I have only three templates storing them as resources worked very good for me. Thanks so much for your answer and comments, greetings from Bogotá - Colombia :D

Comment: ah, sorry, missed that there were only three... I agree w/ you... I thought over the weekend, and typically in the domain spaces that I play in, my clients need to tweek or modify or add new templates pretty regularly, for that reason I realized that I've just moved towards a db based structure that I could wrap some admin screens around... I agree w/ the flat file template though as your best option in this case!